# Is there an implicit barrier at the end of a #pragma omp parallel?

Tags: c++, openmp

Will the main thread wait for all the team spawned at the beginning of the parallel region to finish before running what comes after the parallel region ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, "There is an implicit barrier at the end of the `parallel` construct."

[OpenMP Standard 4.5](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf), 1.3 Execution Model, page 15.

Comment: I thought this was obvious but I think the question becomes more interesting with nested parallelism. This must mean that a parallel construct within a parallel construct has a implicit barrier? Let me reverse that can you remove the implicit barrier for in parallel construct with nested parallelism?

Comment: @Z Boson: the implicit barrier at the end of a parallel region applies to the thread team inside it. The master thread cannot leave the parallel region until all the threads in the team reach the end of it. That is unaffected by whether the parallel region is nested or not, since there is no barrier in the outer level of parallelism...

Comment: @Zboson yes, and I don't believe you can remove it. Even for the combined `parallel` constructs, it is explicitly stated that `nowait` cannot be used.